# Order tweet according to created_at field

Tags: mongodb, twitter

When using the Twitter Stream API to retrieve tweets, each tweet is downloaded together with its

```
created_at
```

field, a `String` field in the format, e.g.,

```
Mon Sep 01 00:00:00 +0000 2014
```

I stored these tweets in a MongoDB database. Now I would like to **order** tweets according to their date, but if I ask MongoDB to order them based on the `created_at` field, which is a string:

```
db.collection.find({},{created_at:1}).sort({created_at:1})
```

the dates will be ordered according to their lexicographic ordering, which is not what I want.

How can I modify the query so as to order them based on date and not on string? I tried with `ISODate` objects, but since the field is string, this does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using MapReduce:

```
db.rawTweets.mapReduce(
    // map
    function() {
        emit(
            // "Thu Jul 17 03:21:42 +0000 2014"
            new Date(Date.parse(this.created_at.replace(/(\+\S+) (.*)/, '$2 $1'))).toLocaleDateString(),
            1
        );
    },

    // reduce
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum(values)
    },

    {
        query: {},
        out: "rawTweetsCount"
    }
)
```

Comment: good solution, but remember that not having dates stored correctly in DB could also prevent you from using these useful "date aggregation operators": http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/ . So, if you have a chance, is always better parse the dates before inserting to mongodb

Comment: Yes, but in case you have a large flow of tweets coming through the Stream API, and your machine is not good enough to process them immediately as they come (as in my case), it is better to initially store them as they are in the DB, and then process them one at a time in further steps. That is why I stored them as provided by the API.